# Why do so many names end in -May or -Mae?

Tags: names

I've been reading articles about trends in names. Apparently names like Bonnie-Mae, Ellie-Mae and Lily-Mae [are trending up in the UK](http://www.babynamewizard.com/archives/2011/8/british-baby-names-vs-american-baby-names) which I find odd in itself (aren't they typically Southern US?) but never mind...

You don't see many endings other than -May or -Mae in double-barreled names. -Anne perhaps, and a few other exceptions, but -Mae seems to dominate.

Any idea where this tradition stems from? Why the skew?

Comment: Perhaps derived from Mary? It makes sense to based double names on short and very common names.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Southern US naming conventions, not *the English language*.

Comment: @Cerberus: I think you're probably right. It seems likely to me the pattern was particularly useful in the American South precisely because they are/were very *traditional*. Thus they stuck with a smaller pool of first names (often even passed down from father to son) - which would have made it more necessary to distinguish *BillyBob* from *BillyRay*, because they'd have so many *Billys* (and not enough different surnames, perhaps).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't know about that...consider how *John/Jan/Jean/Juan/etc.* is very common in all double names. Who knows why local traditions develop as they do...

Comment: @Cerberus: Strictly speaking they're not *really* "double-barreled names" in most cases - it's people being identified by forename *plus* middle name. Which I'm not sure really qualifies as a "tradition" in the traditional sense (sorry! :). It's just something that people in certain areas found *necessary* for the purposes of disambiguation, which presumably was only a problem because they were sticking with a relatively small pool of names in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't know, there are more Jan Willems here than Jans...and whether you spell Jan Willem, Jan-Willem, or Janwillem doesn't make any difference for pronunciation or usage. It may be that the first double names in the Middle Ages started mainly in order to differentiate between people with the same first name but a different middle name, but I'm not sure whether that applies to this situation. It is possible, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: And additional forenames are less common - and, where present, less used - in the UK. It's certainly not an *English language* question.

Comment: Perhaps the recent publicity of Sallie-Mae and Fannie-Mae has allowed the name to seep into our collective unconciousness.